# Extracting information from reddit json and placing it in mysql database using node.js

Tags: mysql, json, database, reddit

I'm trying to extract JSON data from /r/askreddit and put it in a mysql database table called "post". The columns in the table are information such as the title of the post, url of the post, and the username of the poster.

I'm at a complete loss at this point on how to bring the data from the raw JSON into my table from the raw JSON, as I thought it should now be working.

Here is my .js server file, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

let mysql = require('mysql2');
let dbInfo = require('./dbInfo.js');
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");

let app = express();

// Add static route for non-Node.js pages
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Configure body parser for handling post operations
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



app.post('/reddit-import', function (req, res) {
   console.log("Route for the /r/askreddit POST");
  let sql = for (let i=0; i < x.data.children.length; i++) {
    "insert into post (post_title, post_date, post_url, user_name) values (?,?,?,?)"
  };
  let data = [req.body.post_title, req.body.post_date, req.body.post_url, req.body.user_name];

   connection.query(sql,
      data,
      function (errQuery, result) {
         if (errQuery) {
            console.log(errQuery);
            res.json({status: "Error", err: errQuery});
         } else {
            console.log("Insert ID: ", result.insertId);
            res.json({status: result.insertId, err: ""});
         }
      }
   );
});

// Create database connection
console.log('Creating connection...\n');
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: dbInfo.dbHost,
   port: dbInfo.dbPort,
   user: dbInfo.dbUser,
   password: dbInfo.dbPassword,
   database: dbInfo.dbDatabase
});
// Connect to database
connection.connect(function(err) {
   console.log('Connecting to database...\n');

   // Handle any errors
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log('Exiting application...\n');
   } else {
      console.log('Connected to database...\n');
      // Listen for connections
      // Note: Will terminate with an error if database connection
      // is closed
      const ip = 'localhost';
      const port = 8080;
      app.listen(port, ip, function () {
         try {
            console.log('Alumni server app listening on port ' + port);
         } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
         }
      });
   }
});
```